# How can I play a song purchased from Google Play on my iPod?

Tags: itunes, ipod

I purchased the song "What does the fox say?" on Google Play.

I am trying to play this song on my iPod but it won't let me move it from my iTunes library to the device.

What's the problem?

Comment: Drag-and-drop within iTunes won't work?

Comment: What exactly do you purchase from google play? Is it some open format song that you can just download by following this guide? https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1233029?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

Install [this](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/google-play-music/id691797987?mt=8) app(Google Play Music) on your iPod. You should be able to sign-in with your Google-ID, download the songs you own, and play them.

I don't know the application, nor do I use Google Play Music, but I expect this to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play it in your iTunes on your iPod you can go to [Google Play](http://play.google.com) and go to your music. The track will be listed there. Right click it and click download. Drag-and-drop the track into your iTunes and Sync your iPod.

Answer (score 0):

Right click in play.google.com/music folder of your account >> click download on the three button icon >> download >> save it to a folder you can find >> find folder once its fininshed >> drag to itunes

It brings the boxart, track sequencing and everything automatically